# Jira JQL for "all epics which contain at least one ticket which I'm assigned to"

Tags: jira

I'm trying to create a Jira filter which will list every ticket within every epic which I've got any assignments with; basically everything being worked on adjacent to my assignments.

I suspect it'll be some JQL like this:
`("Epic Link" in (SELECT Epic Link FROM Tickets WHERE asignee = me))`

All that I've tried so far is searching for an answer, and I will continue diving deeper into JQL syntax.  Hopefully I'll answer this question myself, but if not:

**Is such syntax possible?  And how would one do it?**

Comment: My comment was deleted, but I'll ask again: If you're voting for close, would you please spare a moment to either suggest a better place to ask this question, or some level of detail on why so that I may improve in the future?

Comment: Is this a JIRA web app/cloud setup or an on prem setup? Are you the administrator? Have you spoken with the administrator?

Comment: This is on cloud, I am not the admin, nor have I spoke to them.  The attempt was a custom filter using JQL.  Any extra information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching, it appears the answer is: no, not right now, probably never

The reason for this is that it requires some form of JOIN to work, which is a hard line that Jira has put between SQL and JQL.  There is the potential for a custom function to be created, and I've put in a [feature request ticket about that](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-discussions/FR-JQL-ability-to-target-quot-epics-which-I-ve-worked-in-quot/m-p/2111177#M17752), but -- as it stands -- this is not possible.